# ASP.NET Impersonation or scheduled task

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have to sync information between a users table in SQL and a user group in active directory.  For example, if a user is entered into SQL table A then they need to be entered into group A and if a user is removed from SQL table A, then remove them from group A.

The application is written in ASP.NET (VB)

I see two solutions:

1) A scheduled task that runs every night syncing the two (written in VB.NET).
2) Use inpersonation so that Active Directory can be updated by the ASP.NET application.  The Web.Config file will have to be encrypted in this solution.

I have read articles online that say it is bad practice to update AD in ASP.NET.  This would suggest that option 1 is the better solution.  Which is the better solution?

Comment: instead of scheduled task I would use Windows Service for option 1

Answer (score 0):

My team considered the same thing and went for a hybrid approach.  The web app puts an AD Change request into a database and the Domain Admins have a desktop app that loads the change request and if they click "Approve", the desktop app immediately applies the change to AD.  It is a little more work for the admins, but there is no need for impersonation and it is much more secure because the admins review and approve each change request, to reduce the chance for something evil or subversive.